# How to combine arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried several solutions but I can't seem to get the result that i want.

I have two arrays:

> $graphone = array ([0,1],[1,2],[3,4]) $graphtwo = array ([4,9],[6,0])
>
> $graphall = array() //to hold graphone and graphtwo

desired output:

```
$graphall = array ([
    graphone = array(
        []...
    ),
    graphtwo = array(
        []...
    )
]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $graphall  = array($graphone , $graphtwo ); ?

Comment: or more like.. $graphall  = array('graphone' => $graphone , 'graphtwo' =>$graphtwo ); if you need the keys in the example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$graphall = array(
    'graphone' => $graphone,
    'graphtwo' => $graphtwo,
);
```

Or to make it shorter:

```
$graphall = array(
    'graphone' => array(array(0,1), array(1,2), array(3,4)),
    'graphtwo' => array(array(4,9), array(6,0)),
);
```

It should be pointed out that there are a syntax errors in the sample array you have provided:

```
$graphone = array ([0,1],[1,2],[3,4]) $graphtwo = array ([4,9],[6,0])
```

You cannot have square brackets the way you have them here and you are missing the line ending semi-colons. It should look like this:

```
$graphone = array(array(0,1), array(1,2), array(3,4));
$graphtwo = array(array(4,9), array(6,0));
```

Comment: Well, you we're faster than me, with the same exact formatting :)

Comment: actually, as of php 5.4(in beta right now), square brackets are a valid array constructor syntax :)

Comment: @chris correct, but I like to try to keep my answers newbie and production server ready :)

Answer (score 2):

For the desired output, you will have to use this:

```
$graphall = array(
    'graphone' => $graphone,
    'graphtwo' => $graphtwo
);
```

No need to have it on seperated lines, I just prefer to have it on more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

I 'd also like to mention

```
$graphall = compact('graphone', 'graphtwo');
```

as a less-known alternative to the standard

```
$graphall = array( 
    'graphone' => $graphone, 
    'graphtwo' => $graphtwo, 
);
```

The [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function returns an array with names of variables as keys and their contents as values.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if i understood you right, but i think your are looking for this:

```
$graphone = array ([0,1],[1,2],[3,4]);
$graphtwo = array ([4,9],[6,0]);

$graphall = array(
    'graphone'=>$graphone,
    'graphtwo'=>$graphtwo
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
  $graphall = array($graphone, $gpraphtwo);
```